# How do you select the "1st to 11th" element in a column in sqlite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite

So I want to select the first eleven elements in a column and then select from the 12th to the 22nd. How do you select a specific range from a column in an Sqlite3 DB?

Comment: Well I tried many things such as if statements to stop after the 11th but this was the solution "SELECT my_column FROM mytable LIMIT 11,11" this skips the first 11 and selects the next 11 so from 12 to 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LIMIT clause to select a given number of elements, and OFFSET to skip a given number of them. That is,

```
SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 11 OFFSET 11
```

will return elements 12th to 22nd.

Comment: This worked but instead of offset I used a comma "SELECT column_name FROM mytable LIMIT 11,11"

Comment: It is also valid, but be careful that in this case the offset is the first number and the limit the second.

Comment: exactly thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT column_name FROM database_name WHERE condition LIMIT start_index,num_records"
```

you might also try looking at https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html